is workmanager still working when app is swipe up from recent app list?
`I want functionality like my app will fetch data from api and updates data in db in every 15-16 minutes so i use workmanager periodic task for that. But workmanager only works when app is in background(recent app list) and if i swipe up from recent app list(background) then work manager not working anymore and when i start my app again then only it works. My device is samsung f62. I also try to auto start true from setting but auto start feature is not their and also battery optimization is unrestricted that also not working.
Worker class -:
@HiltWorker
class NewsWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context,
    @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val newsRepository = ServiceLocator.newsRepository
        Log.d("worker call", "this is a worker call")
        var result: Result? = null
        try {
            newsRepository.workManagerRequest()
                .catch {
                    result = Result.failure()
                    Log.d("worker call", "this is a worker call failure from 1st catch")
                }
                .collect { flowResult ->
                    when (flowResult) {
                        is Results.Success -> {
                            Log.d("worker call", "this is a worker call Success")
                            // Handle the successful case
                            // You can process the PagingData here
                            showNotification()
                        }
                        is Results.Error -> {
                            Log.d("worker call", "this is a worker call failure from Result.Error")
                            // Handle the error case
                            result = Result.failure()
                        }
                    }
                    if (result != null) return@collect
                }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("worker call", "this is a worker call failure from second catch :$e")
            result = Result.failure()
        }
        return result ?: Result.success()
    }

    private fun showNotification() {
        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    applicationContext,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // Permission is granted, proceed with creating the channel
                val channel = NotificationChannel(
                    "News Channel ID",
                    "News Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                )
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            } else {
                // Permission is not granted, show a dialog to ask for permission
                return
            }
        }

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "News Channel ID")
            .setContentTitle("News")
            .setContentText("You have new updated news please check it out")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.news)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}

object ServiceLocator {
    lateinit var newsRepository: NewsRepository
}

Application class -:
@HiltAndroidApp 
class NewsApp: Application() , Configuration.Provider{

@Inject
lateinit var hiltWorkerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    setUpWorker()
}

override val workManagerConfiguration: Configuration
    get() = Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(hiltWorkerFactory)
        .build()

private fun setUpWorker() {
    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .build()
    val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NewsWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        NewsWorker::class.java.name,
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        workRequest
    )
}
}

    Manifest -:
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:node="merge">
        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:value="androidx.startup"
            tools:node="remove" />
    </provider>

Dependecy-:
//dagger-hilt for worker
implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0")
kapt ("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")

//Work manager
implementation ("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1")

Auto start settings is not their and battery optimization is unrestricted but not works
`
